# Best implementation of a global variable

Tags: c++, class, object

I have a variable in one of my classes:

```
Object * myObject;
```

Which I now need my other classes to be able to access in other classes.

Whats the best way to be able to access it?

Is the following implementation correct?

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

#include "Object.h"

Object * myObject[5][5];

#endif
```

EDIT:

A little more info, basically I have class A and class B.

class A has the variable myObject which class B needs to access. Class A also has a object of class B which means I cant include the header of class A in class B's header as class A has the header include of class B in it.

Comment: If it's already inside a class, you could simply pass an object of that class wherever it's needed. Instantiate it in `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a reference to the object to other interested classes would be preferable.  Assuming you can't do this and really need a global, you'd be better with

```
extern Object * myObject;
```

in globals.h and

```
Object * myObject;
```

in globals.cpp

Otherwise each source file which includes globals.h will pick up a duplicate definition of `myObject`

Answer (score 2):

If all your classes are sharing the same object you could potentially add it to a base class as a static variable.

```
class base
{
    static Object* myObject;
};

class inherit : base
{
    void foo()
    {
         // can access myObject
    }
};

class inherit2 : base
{
    void bar()
    {
         // can access myObject
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The most socially acceptable solution for storing a global variable is definitely a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). A typical implementation in C++ would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
public:
        static Singleton& Get() {
                static Singleton singleton;
                return singleton;
        }

        void DoSomething() { cout << "Something!\n"; }

private:
        Singleton() {}
};

int main()
{
        Singleton::Get().DoSomething();
}
```

The major advantage of this over a typical global variable is that you have more control over how the object is constructed.

Just don't forget that it's still a global variable, so you should only use it when it's the least-evil alternative.

Comment: Quick note about this: before c++11 (vs 2012, and g++4.7 i think) this is unsafe in a multithreaded environment; to illustrate, add `Sleep(3000); cout << "Done constructing" << endl;` in the constructor for Singleton and launch 3 threads that call `Get().DoSomething()`. You will see 'Something!' twice before you see the message that construction is done.  i.e., you will have been working with an unconstructed object! This is resolved in the new standard

Comment: -1 Singletons are not a way of making a global variable, they are a way of ensuring a class has only one instance. It's better to use a static member or simply a global.

Comment: Yes, they ensure that you only have a single instance of your global variable, but it's still just a kind of global variable. The question was asking for implementations of global variables, and you're fooling yourself if you don't believe that singletons belong under that umbrella.

Comment: Yes, they are global, but they are not socially acceptable, and he is getting more than just a global, he is a getting a single instance of class for the duration of the program.

Comment: There's a world of difference between "socially acceptable" and "most socially acceptable". My answer is quite explicit about singletons still being evil. And I wouldn't say a singleton gives you more than a global; singletons are actually more restricted. They have shorter duration (because they're instantiated on first use instead of at program startup) and you're limited to just one instance of your class. You get _less_ with a singleton. _On purpose_.

Comment: My "more" has the same meaning as your "less". He is not getting only a global, he is getting a singleton (obviously), which has more semantic meaning and more restrictions. And I still disagree that singletons are the "most sociable acceptable" solution for a global variable.